# ¿Cómo puedo extraer las líneas de /etc/passwd cuyo UID solo contenga un único número?

Tags: linux, bash

En el fichero /etc/passwd debo filtrar el UID de todos los usuarios que solo sean de una sola cifra.

Para ellos, debe aparecer la línea entera del tipo:

```
usuario:x:uid_filtrado:guid:nombredelusuario:directoriohome:shell
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, ¿podrías agregar un __[mcve]__ que muestre el problema que estás enfrentando al intentarlo? Si buscas ideas, consejos o recomendaciones, tal vez sea mejor que uses Google. Tal como está tu pregunta será propuesta para cierre, ya que es demasiado amplia o solicita opiniones. Te invito a leer esta guía: __[ask]__.

Comment: A ver es que no se como hacer esto, necesito filtrar el UID de todos los usuarios y que solo sea de 1 cifra y que te muestre toda la linea.

Comment: Puedes __[edit]__ tu pregunta para agregar la información que desees. Te aconsejo que, en la medida de lo posible, agregues un __[mcve]__ que ilustre tu problema real y concreto.

Comment: Lo que planteas es bastante fácil usando por ejemplo awk. Sin embargo, esto no es un sitio donde programemos para ti, sino que queremos ayudarte en base a lo que ya tienes. ¿Podrías enseñárnoslo para que podamos ayudarte? Dale a [edit] para agregarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución a lo que planteas es utilizar AWK.

```
awk -F: 'length($3) == 1' /etc/passwd
```

En primer lugar, entendamos el funcionamiento básico del lenguaje AWK.

```
SINTAXIS: awk [opciones] 'expresión {acción}' [fichero]
```

En resumen, AWK permite evaluar una **expresión** para cada linea de entrada y si la evaluación de 
la expresión resulta positiva, se realiza la **acción** asociada.
En caso de no definir una expresión, tendremos que indicar de forma 
implicita la acción que será ejecutada para cada una de las lineas.
Caso contrario, si determinamos una expresión pero no una acción, la acción por defecto 
es enviar a la salida estandar cada linea que cumpla con la expresión.
Por lo tanto, simpre debemos definir la expresión y/o la acción.

[**fichero**] permite indicar el archivo que será procesado, de no indicarse  AWK lee de la entrada estandar.

Ahora que tenemos claro el funcionamiento básico, analizemos cada una de las partes de la solución planteada:

**-F: (-F field-separator)**
Esta es una de las tantas opciones de linea de comandos presentes en AWK, esta permite 
determinar cual sera el separador de campos (field-separator), por defecto es un espacio en blanco ' '.
Si nos detenemos a observar el formato del archivo /etc/passwd, podemos ver que existe un claro 
separador de campos el caracter ':'.
Teniendo esto en cuenta podemos obtener de forma individual el valor UID de cada linea, ya que 
cada uno de los campos quedara almacendo en un variable del estilo $1, $2, $3, $N..., 
siendo N el número de campo. En este caso el UID ocupa el campo $3.

**length($3) == 1** (Expresión)

Ahora que tenemos el UID debemos conocer el número de caracteres de este, para esto podemos utilizar 
la funcion length() de AWK la cual retorna dicho número. 
Por ultimo evaluamos si este es igual a 1, de ser así enviamos a la salida estandar la linea actual, ya que no hemos indicado ninguna acción.